# Open URL via IP

Tags: php, nginx

I have remote server machine with nginx server on it. I created `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` folders, I have a folder in it called `example.com` with the following configuration:

```
#HTTP serve
#
server {
        listen   80;

        root /var/www/example.com/www/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log combined buffer=1024k;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

        client_max_body_size 128M;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 last;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                if (!-f $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name){
                        return 404;
                }

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
                proxy_read_timeout 600s;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

It should redirect me to `/var/www/example.com/www` when I enter `http://example.com/` url in the browser. But I don't have this domain yet, and I want to open it via server IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. How do I do that?

Should I rename the folder to IP? I couldn't access other folders then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stateed by @ceejayoz and confirmed by http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html, you can specify the IP address under server_name:

> If someone makes a request using an IP address instead of a server name, the “Host” request header field will contain the IP address and the request can be handled using the IP address as the server name:

Otherwise, the default action is to use the first server in the config file if no server_name is matched.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#mixed_name_ip_based_servers

> In this configuration nginx tests only the request’s header field “Host” to determine which server the request should be routed to. If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default server for this port. In the configuration above, the default server is the first one — which is nginx’s standard default behaviour.

You can look into the default_server option for the server_name as described in the second link.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I did, but it didn't work. I changed it to `listen 91.266.10.15:80` but I'm still getting connection timeout.

Comment: You should never get a connection timeout if nginx is properly listening on the port.  So there is another issue, make sure port 80 is open in your firewall and nginx is listening to it using `netstat -natp`

Comment: It shows `tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11901/nginx: master`, nginx is up and running but still nothing.

Comment: Your server is blocking connections somewhere, most likely in the firewall.